# Nested Scroll Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have multiple LazyColumn. I need a page including common scroll over all lists.
I tried add .nestedScroll(object: NestedScrollConnection) to Column, but it doesn't work.

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
    ) {
        Toolbar(toolbarOffsetHeightPx)
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)) {
            items(parameters) { CarParameter(it) }
        }
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)) {
            items(carInfoList) { CarInfo(it) }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use items() multiple times in one LazyColumn

```
LazyColumn {
  item { Toolbar() }
  items(...) { ... }
  items(...) { ... }
}
```